# implementation of LinkedList without last node

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have been asked to re-implement a linked list without the use of a tail. So I have to change its methods so it can work without using a tail node.

The `removeLast` method confused me: here is what I tried to do, but it didn't remove the node.

What is wrong with my attempt?

```
public E removeLast()
{
    if(isEmpty()) return null;
    Node<E> temp=head;

    while (temp.getNext()!=null) {
        temp=temp.getNext();
    }
    E a=temp.getData();
    temp=null;
    size--;
    // if(head==temp)
    if (head.getNext()==null)
        head=null;

    return a;
}
```

Test class

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    LinkedListWm<Integer> r = new LinkedListWm<>();
    r.addFirst(1);
    r.addFirst(3);
    r.addFirst(7);
    r.addFirst(50);
    r.addLast(5);
    System.out.println(r.last());
    System.out.println(r.first());
    r.removeLast();
    System.out.println(r.last());
    r.removeFirst();
    r.display();
}
```

Comment: is it homework? Please do not do so in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the node that precedes `temp`. You'll need it to end the list at the preceding node, by setting its `next` property to null.

Currently you try to do that with:

```
temp = null;
```

...but that is just clearing the content of the variable `temp`. It does not alter the list. For that to happen, you must alter a `next` property.

So define a `prev` variable that will follow after `temp`:

```
Node<E> prev = null;

while (temp.getNext()!=null) {
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp.getNext();
}
```

And instead of:

```
temp = null;
```

do:

```
prev.next = null;
```

Of course, the latter can only happen when `prev` is not null, or in other words, when `head` is not the last node (i.e. `temp`).

So taking it all together:

```
public E removeLast()
{
    if (isEmpty()) return null;
    Node<E> prev = null;
    Node<E> temp = head;
    
    while (temp.getNext() != null) {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }
    
    size--;
    if (prev == null)
        head = null;
    else
        prev.next = null;
        
    return temp.getData();
}
```